# Accidental reverse order of menu items in one menu

Tags: menus, order

On my website I have two menus - one on the top and the second which appears after scrolling down.

The order of menu items is correct in "scrolling-menu", and in the "top-menu" it's reversed.

What did I wrong?

```
  <div id="scrolling-menu">
      <div  class="container">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1"><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/logo.png" class="img-responsive" /></div>
              <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-1">
                  <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu', 'depth' => 1)); ?>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <header>
          <div class="container">
                <div id="logo"></div>
                <div id="mainnav">
                        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu', 'depth' => 1)); ?>
                </div>
          </div>
  </header>
```

At first both menus were working correctly but then I realised that I forgot to install the menu in functions.php. The problem started after adding the file  but after deleting it the problem remains.

My functions.php file looked like that (it's deleted now):

```
    <?php
    function register_my_menus() {
    register_nav_menus(
    array( 'header-menu' => __( 'Header Menu' ))
    );
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu that is reversed is because it is `float:right;`. That's the expected behavior when you use `float:right;`.

This has nothing to do with WordPress itself it is a purely CSS issue.

Comment: No way! I had no idea. Thank you very much, now it works just fine! But, anyway, it's strange that the problem appeared after I added functions.php. Maybe I have some code issue. Thank you!:)